# Find three or more consecutive negative numbers and remove the rows from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my sample data:

```
df = data.frame(id=rep(c(123,456,789),each=5),day=rep(c(1:5),3),measure=c(2.2,3.4,2.1,-0.2,-1.2,3.4,2.4,-2.2,-3.1,-1.7,3.9,5.4,-1,3.2,4.2))

    id day measure
1  123   1     2.2
2  123   2     3.4
3  123   3     2.1
4  123   4    -0.2
5  123   5    -1.2
6  456   1     3.4
7  456   2     2.4
8  456   3    -2.2
9  456   4    -3.1
10 456   5    -1.7
11 789   1     3.9
12 789   2     5.4
13 789   3    -1.0
14 789   4     3.2
15 789   5     4.2
```

Each individual has five days of data.

I want to find places in df$measure for each individual, where there are three or more consecutive negative values WITHIN EACH INDIVIDUAL, and drop those rows. If there are two or less consecutive negative values, simply set the values to 0.

Individual 123 has two negative values at the end, so change the value to 0
Individual 456 has three negative values at the end, so drop those rows
Individual 789 has one negative value at day 3, so change the value to 0

Result:

```
    id day measure
1  123   1     2.2
2  123   2     3.4
3  123   3     2.1
4  123   4    0
5  123   5    0
6  456   1     3.4
7  456   2     2.4
8 789   1     3.9
9 789   2     5.4
10 789   3    0
11 789   4     3.2
12 789   5     4.2
```

What I have so far:

If I first turn all the negative values in df$measure into 0..

```
df$measure[df$measure < 0] <- 0
```

Then somehow use rle:

```
m = rle(df$measure)

Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:12] 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 ...
  values : num [1:12] 2.2 3.4 2.1 0 3.4 2.4 0 3.9 5.4 0 ...
```

and work out from m$lengths and m$values the indices of the 0's that are 3 or more consecutive - those need to be removed.

But it needs to be checked separately for each ID?

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table` and make use of `rleid`, to group the run-length-encoding by id

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

## indicate wich measure values are negative
df[, neg := measure < 0]
## use run-length-encoding by each id, on the 'neg' column
df[, rl := rleid(neg), by = id]

## identify how many of each 'rl' are in each group
df[, rl_len := .N, by=.(id, rl)]

## drop values
df <- df[!(neg & rl_len >= 3)]

## set to 0
df[neg == 1, measure := 0]
df
#      id day measure   neg rl rl_len
#  1: 123   1     2.2 FALSE  1      3
#  2: 123   2     3.4 FALSE  1      3
#  3: 123   3     2.1 FALSE  1      3
#  4: 123   4     0.0  TRUE  2      2
#  5: 123   5     0.0  TRUE  2      2
#  6: 456   1     3.4 FALSE  1      2
#  7: 456   2     2.4 FALSE  1      2
#  8: 789   1     3.9 FALSE  1      2
#  9: 789   2     5.4 FALSE  1      2
# 10: 789   3     0.0  TRUE  2      1
# 11: 789   4     3.2 FALSE  3      2
# 12: 789   5     4.2 FALSE  3      2
```

Answer (score 5):

Another base R version with `ave` using the old "reverse the reverse of a negated logical check" trick to get an appropriate counter.

Since:

```
with(df, rev(cumsum(!(rev(measure) < 0))) )
#[1] 9 8 7 6 6 6 5 4 4 4 4 3 2 2 1
# compare the equivalent of df$id groups
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

When combined with the `id`, you can just check the length:

```
df[with(df, ave(measure, list(id, rev(cumsum(!(rev(measure) < 0)))), FUN=length) < 3 ),]

#    id day measure
#1  123   1     2.2
#2  123   2     3.4
#3  123   3     2.1
#4  123   4    -0.2
#5  123   5    -1.2
#6  456   1     3.4
#7  456   2     2.4
#11 789   1     3.9
#12 789   2     5.4
#13 789   3    -1.0
#14 789   4     3.2
#15 789   5     4.2
```

Answer (score 4):

We get the `rle` of the logical vector (`!df$measure` - gives TRUE for 0 values and all others FALSE) from 'measure' , assign the 'values' vector (from `rle`) that have 'lengths' less than 3 to FALSE, negate it (`!`) and subset the dataset.

```
df[!inverse.rle(within.list(rle(!df$measure), values[lengths<3] <- FALSE)),]
#    id day measure
#1  123   1     2.2
#2  123   2     3.4
#3  123   3     2.1
#4  123   4     0.0
#5  123   5     0.0
#6  456   1     3.4
#7  456   2     2.4
#11 789   1     3.9
#12 789   2     5.4
#13 789   3     0.0
#14 789   4     3.2
#15 789   5     4.2
```

NOTE:  The above result matches the OP's expected output because the 0 values are not consecutive between adjacent 'id'.  If we need to do this within each 'id', use any of the group by techniques.  In `base R`, we can do this with `ave`

```
indx <- with(df, !ave(!measure, id, FUN = function(x) {
                 inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), values[lengths<3] <- FALSE))
              }))
df[indx,]
#    id day measure
#1  123   1     2.2
#2  123   2     3.4
#3  123   3     2.1
#4  123   4     0.0
#5  123   5     0.0
#6  456   1     3.4
#7  456   2     2.4
#11 789   1     3.9
#12 789   2     5.4
#13 789   3     0.0
#14 789   4     3.2
#15 789   5     4.2
```

---

Or we can use `rleid` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'id' and the run-length-id of the negated 'measure', get a logical index column (`!(!measure & .N >2)`) to subset the rows from the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, !(!measure & .N >2), .(id, rleid(!measure))]$V1]
#     id day measure
# 1: 123   1     2.2
# 2: 123   2     3.4
# 3: 123   3     2.1
# 4: 123   4     0.0
# 5: 123   5     0.0
# 6: 456   1     3.4
# 7: 456   2     2.4
# 8: 789   1     3.9
# 9: 789   2     5.4
#10: 789   3     0.0
#11: 789   4     3.2
#12: 789   5     4.2
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, gr = cumsum(c(0,abs(diff(!measure))))) %>% 
  filter(!(all(!measure) & n() >2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-gr)
#      id   day measure
#    (dbl) (int)   (dbl)
#1    123     1     2.2
#2    123     2     3.4
#3    123     3     2.1
#4    123     4     0.0
#5    123     5     0.0
#6    456     1     3.4
#7    456     2     2.4
#8    789     1     3.9
#9    789     2     5.4
#10   789     3     0.0
#11   789     4     3.2
#12   789     5     4.2
```

NOTE2: Used the data after replacing the negative values with 0.